# How should I define a User?

Tags: freeradius

I am familiar with a RADIUS Server that runs over a windows OS (TekRADIUS). Any of the users that I have set there are part of a Default group with a certain test and Vendor definition.
Each of the users have the following attributes:

1. User-Password, of a type Check, and its Value is the Password
2. Class, of a type Success-Reply, and its Value is 4/2/1 (each value is marking the user with its privilegdes)

I want to be able to use FreeRadius and I don't know how should I define the attributes. It looks like FreeRadius is using other terminology and therefore my settings are invalid.

Can anyone please tell me how to translate the attributes in order to make them fit into the FreeRadius syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question.

```
user1       Cleartext-Password := "user1"
            Class = 0x34
```

or

```
user1       Cleartext-Password := "user1"
            Class = 4
```

Class values 4/2/1 will grant the privileges as expected